# jQuery toggle is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var resultsList = $("#test");
resultsList.text("Hello. This is jQuery!");

var tB = jQuery("#toggleButton");

tB.on("click", function() {
    resultsList.toggle(400);
});
```

I believe the syntax is correct because the browser console is not reporting any error.

On loading the page, the toggle is not working as expected. Any idea, what am I missing here?

My HTML is :

```
<div id="results" class="bordered-image"> 
    <button id="#toggleButton">Hide</button> 
    <div id="test">This is where results will live...eventually.</div>     
</div>
```

Comment: If the code is included in `<head>`, either wrap it in `ready` or move it to the bottom of `<body>`, is this the case?

Comment: please give complete html here, because tooggle also want proper HTML to work.

Comment: <div id="results" class="bordered-image">
        <button id="#toggleButton">Hide</button>
        <div id="test">This is where results will live...eventually.</div>
      </div>

Comment: Is it possible the button shows up before the jQuery library loads and that's why the toggle is not working?

Comment: It looks like rather this is a typo `id="#toggleButton"` should be `id="toggleButton"` If that's the case we can close this question as being a typographical error.

Comment: also your html is not correct id should not start with #, it should be simple name without hash, in your case it is toggleButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id="toggleButton" instead of id="#toggleButton" will do.

Comment: Then flag this question as a typographical error... Rather than stating what I already mentioned 20 minutes ago.

Comment: How to flag, I don't know !! Can you tell me ? I can do .

Comment: Since the question was simply a typographical error high rep users can give a close vote to the question, where other users can flag it as such. More than likely the question will be removed, as typos are not helpful for others. If you look below the content of the question there should be a small *"flag"* button.

Answer (score 2):

Put the Jquery code into document.ready() like this: Check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/nfcpm06u/1/) also.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var resultsList = $("#test");
        resultsList.text("Hello. This is jQuery!");

        var tB = jQuery("#toggleButton");

        tB.on("click", function() {
            resultsList.toggle(400);
        });
    });
```

Your id attribute should be id="toggleButton" instead of id="#toggleButton"

**HTML**:

```
<div id="results" class="bordered-image"> 
    <button id="toggleButton">Hide</button> 
    <div id="test">This is where results will live...eventually.</div>     
</div>
```

Comment: Can you check the HTML in the fiddle. Hope it is ok rt

Comment: My code is still not working, despite being inside the document ready function. I have uploaded my files here at: http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=01102376399704095945&t=0110237639970409594583731(not sure if this is the safest method)

Comment: Your HTML is fine. I mean the problem with the OP's code could of been from their HTML.

Comment: @Sharktooth Did you fix the problem with your HTML (`id="#toggleButton"`), which I mentioned in a comment to your question?

Comment: Just noticed. And yes, I did. It was a stupid error :/

Comment: Your id attribute should be id="toggleButton" instead of id="#toggleButton"

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside the document ready function.

Comment: A bit more explanation and code example would have been better.

Answer (score 0):

see this example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="results" class="bordered-image"> 
    <button id="toggleButton">Hide</button> 
    <div id="test">This is where results will live...eventually.</div>     
</div>

</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var resultsList = $("#test");
    resultsList.text("Hello. This is jQuery!");
    $("#toggleButton").click(function() {
        resultsList.toggle(400);
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="results" class="bordered-image"> 
<button id="#toggleButton" onclick="myff();">Hide</button> 
 <div id="test">This is where results will live...eventually.</div>     
</div>

 <script>
 function myff(){

  $("#test").toggle();  
  }

</script>
```